# Create a new column within a partition with STRING VALUES, based on another column with numerical values

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

The below is a partition out of a larger table by Category and sub category, I've given an example based on only a part of the data in category.

| Category | Sub Category | Stock_date | demand in tonnes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Red Apple | 2023-01-22 | 5 |
| Apple | Red Apple | 2023-02-22 | 6 |
| Apple | Red Apple | 2023-03-22 | 7 |
| Apple | Red Apple | 2023-04-22 | 4 |
| Apple | Green Apple | 2023-01-22 | 10 |
| Apple | Green Apple | 2023-02-22 | 15 |
| Apple | Green Apple | 2023-03-22 | 3 |
| Apple | Green Apple | 2023-04-22 | 1 |

Within each sub-category, I need to be able to generate a string value based on where MAX demand has been reached when ordered by DATE, having string value 'BEFORE' and 'AFTER' based on this. The table I am looking for is as below.

| Category | Sub Category | Stock_date | demand in tonnes | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Red Apple | 2023-01-22 | 5 | BEFORE |
| Apple | Red Apple | 2023-02-22 | 6 | BEFORE |
| Apple | Red Apple | 2023-03-22 | 7 | MAXIMUM |
| Apple | Red Apple | 2023-04-22 | 4 | AFTER |
| Apple | Green Apple | 2023-01-22 | 10 | BEFORE |
| Apple | Green Apple | 2023-02-22 | 15 | MAXIMUM |
| Apple | Green Apple | 2023-03-22 | 3 | AFTER |
| Apple | Green Apple | 2023-04-22 | 1 | AFTER |

I have tried a confusing combination of CASE statements that throw errors with the partitioning. Used Frames within the partition with errors too. Will be grateful for any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no ties with the max value for each sub-category, you may try the following using the `max` window function and `first_value` function:

```
select category, sub_category, stock_date, demand_in_tonnes,
  case 
    when stock_date = max_dem_dt and demand_in_tonnes = max_dem then 'MAXIMUM'
    when stock_date < max_dem_dt then 'BEFORE'
    else 'AFTER'
  end as "Result"
from
(
  select *,
    max(demand_in_tonnes) over (partition by Category, Sub_Category) as max_dem,
    first_value(Stock_date) over (partition by Category, Sub_Category order by demand_in_tonnes desc) max_dem_dt
  from table_name
) T
order by category, sub_category, stock_date
```

If the stock_date is unique per subcategory, you may remove the second condition in the first when (`and demand_in_tonnes = max_dem`) and use only the `first_value` function.

[demo on Postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/RCUGZ8FK)